# MSChart control .net 3.5 sp1 - Inverted Y axis issue

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

I have a chart control with inverted y axis. It always eats up one day from top.

```
 cht1.ChartAreas["TimeOfNight"].AxisY.Minimum = startTime.AddDays(-1).ToOADate();
 cht1.ChartAreas["TimeOfNight"].AxisY.Maximum = endTime.AddDays(1).ToOADate();
```

But chart still eats a day! I created a sample project so that you guys can have a look. Behaviour is quite random :(.

Image displaying chart and y axis min/max . See image:

[image: http://img141.imageshack.us/i/10869903.png/]

source code and executable: [Available on Rapidshare](http://rapidshare.com/files/454233079/InvertedYAxis.zip)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is neither random nor unexpected.

Change this line:

```
cht1.ChartAreas["TimeOfNight"].AxisY.Minimum = startTime.AddDays(-1).ToOADate();
```

to

```
cht1.ChartAreas["TimeOfNight"].AxisY.Minimum = startTime.AddDays(-3).ToOADate();
```

And see what it looks like.

Comment: Thansk for you reply. Well I could do that but I need a fix not hack. I need to know the y location for the date so that I can dynamically add some text on the right side of the y axis. Please help out with a fix.. thanks.

Comment: Let me be precise:
var yAxisLocation = cht1.ChartAreas["TimeOfNight"].AxisY.ValueToPosition(startTime.Date.ToOADate());
gives wrong y value location due to this bug :(

Comment: @user507774 ~ Sorry, I was away in the evening last night, so I did not see these responses. Let me have until this evening and I may can find something for you, but I suggest that if you have found a bug, and not a misunderstood behavior, that you should consider writing a bugreport with Microsoft. Otherwise, I am more than happy to run this through reflector and see what it's doing "incorrectly" here.

Comment: I have been through reflector and been through used reflection to change some private properties yesterday. All values are set correctly and charting thinks it has plotted everything correctly! Its gives wrong values for the Y axis :(. I am thinking to contact MS today.

Comment: @User507774 I would encourage that then, based on what you are saying here.